# PrimeNg p-dropdown component Space bar is not entering space to my input box

Tags: input, primeng, p-dropdown

I'm using

```
<div>
   <p-dropdown[options]="states" filterBy="name" 
  [formControl]="$any(formGroup).get('state')" optionLabel="name" 
  [editable]="true" 
  (onFilter)="customFilter($event)" placeholder="Select State"\>
   </p-dropdown>
</div>
```

and I have used this

```
editable=true
```

which means It will take input text in it so It is taking input but not taking space entered value eg: If I pass United and then press space it is not allowing me to use space bar.

Currently taking **UnitedStates** as input value I wanna make that input as ***United States*** [ make use of space bar of keyboard ]

Comment: Could you please provide a stackblitz?